# snaps unable to start

Tags: snap

I have now installed ECLIPSE and NETBEANS as snaps.
When I attempt to launch either from the command-line, I fail with error "unable to create user data file ~/snap/productname/number  (permission denied).
If I do ls -lR ~/snap, I see that all the directories involved do in fact exist (and are writable).

Comment: On 'snapcraft.io' I find a problem report involving cases when $HOME != /home/$USER.  So it is probably relevant that my system uses $HOME==/home/users/$USER.  I really do not want to change this.

Answer (score 0):

So, muttering many a curse into my beard, I moved $HOME's for all my users so they are where the Powers have decided they must be, and now it works!